# HTML and CSS: Adding more tables to the screen depending on the amount of rows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I am developing a website for a friend, and this website will have a table of data, however for his own reasons he doesn't want to scroll down to see the data, he wants the data to be spread out horizontally so he can use multiple screens to see all the data.

The best Idea i came up with was to create a horizontal table, which basically means that instead of the scrolling down to see more data, I create a new table on the right to the last table to hold additional rows.

So lets say that each table should have no more than 20 rows, if there are more rows then we create a new table placed on the right of the table containing the first 20 rows and so on.

Whats the best way to do this from a HTML and CSS layout perspective? I will be creating the tables using dojo enhanced grids and grids will be added dynamically, I dont need any code for this part.

So maybe I have a empty div element and append the grids to that div and have them align right?

I am not saying this is best method to do this so if someone has a better method of meeting the requirement I would love to hear it and learn from it.

EDIT:

Just to clarify I don't need JavaScript code or any other code to dynamically add the grids.

I just want to know the HTML and CSS structure should be.

e.g I have a container Div of a fixed height, and I add elements to it and the elements should have x and y CSS properties etc.

Thanks

Comment: Breaking up your collection of tabular data across multiple tables sounds like a bad idea from a semantic standpoint.

Comment: I am making a website for my friend and he doesn't want to scroll down, he wants to have multiple screens and scroll horizontally. 

if you have a better way of meeting this requirement please share it?

Comment: Your options greatly depend on the type/amount of data you have.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#tables").append(
    $("<table style='float:left;border: 1px solid black'>").append(
        $("<tr>").append(
            $("<td>").html(
                "content"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7PpRB/1/

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use PHP for this. if you're not familiar with it, you can keep it simple.

```
echo '<table>';

for($i = 0; $i < total_elements; $i++){
    echo '<tr><td>'./*Whatever you want to insert.*/.'</td></tr>';

    if($i % 20 = 0)
        echo '</table><table>'
}

echo '</table>';
```

It's up to you to insert the styles.

Comment: The question asks for a HTML- and CSS-only solution.

Comment: I know, but to dynamically create a new table you can't use HTML and CSS. If you know the amount of elements you're going to insert beforehand, than you can use the answer of nahum, otherwise you should consider using PHP (and alternatively javascript).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I wasn't looking for how to create the tables dynamically, just on what would be the best way to lay them out.

Answer (score -1):

you could do it with divs and add a new div when you need a new information, I dont recommend the use of tables because every time you add a new table next to the other is like have a different context of information.

--css

```
.holder{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  background:#333;
  color:#FFF;  
  font-family:Arial; 
}

.holder.zebra{
  background:#222;
}

.holder div.row{
  padding:10px;  
}

.break{
  clear:both;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  display:block; 
}

table{
  margin-top:10px;

  background:#333;
  float:left;
  color:#FFF;
  font-family:Arial;
}

table td, table th{
  padding:5px;
  text-align:left;
}
```

-- table solution

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>title 1</th>
    <th>title 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content 1</td>
    <td>content 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>title 1</th>
    <th>title 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content 1</td>
    <td>content 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

-- Div solution

```
<!-- could be the table 1 -->
<div class="holder">
  <div class="row">content 1</div>
  <div class="row">content 2</div>
  <div class="row">content 3</div>
</div>
<!-- could be the table 2 -->
<div class="holder zebra">
  <div class="row">content 1</div>
  <div class="row">content 2</div>
  <div class="row">content 3</div>
</div>
<!-- could be the table 3 -->
<div class="holder">
  <div class="row">content 1</div>
  <div class="row">content 2</div>
  <div class="row">content 3</div>
</div>
```

here is the codepen you can watch the result http://cdpn.io/sAoxB

EDIT:

IM NOT SAYING this is a good practice I'm only answer the question, Please dont downvote without reason. thanks

[image: RESULT]

Comment: Multiple tables a single collection of tabular data or taking tabular data out of a table... I honestly can't decide which is worse.

Comment: wtf!! why I got a minus 1 ??? well ... both are not 100% good answers, while table next to another table is like saying in the code you have different data displays, using div instead of table in a data tabular context is not at all correct, but for IMHO is more clean.

Comment: btw, he is not saying all his content is TABULAR DATA so my answer is perfect fine...

Comment: He didn't say that his data *isn't* tabular.  He just says "I have some data that's in a table".  Maybe it *doesn't* belong in a table, but that doesn't mean it belongs in a div either.  Just because your answer functions doesn't mean it is a good answer.

Comment: ok if does not below to a table or div, where does below? haha man really if you dont have anything for help, don't disturb other people answer. If not below to a div, table should be <nav> or <dd> either where below, my approach is the same with any tag, so is a GOOD answer...